# iOS Sticker Pack with Horizontal Menu?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-stickers

I have a bunch of stickers that should be grouped together. I want a horizontal scroll at the top and when a user selections a group I want to load that group underneath just like the apple sticker app (Memoji Stickers) pictured below....

Is this available to the public?

[image]

Comment: You would have to do this as a custom iMessage app - it is not available if you are making a simple sticker pack.

Comment: Im fine with a custom iMessage app. Can you point me in the right direction? Is it simply loading a horizontal scroll and a table view?

Comment: I think two separate collection views would be the way - the top one horizontal.